# Divergence theory interpretation

Tags: vector-fields, divergence-theorem

The divergence theory states that

$ \iiint\limits_T \nabla \cdot  F \;  dxdydz =  \iint\limits_S F \cdot n \; dA $

where $ F=[F_1,F_2,F_3]$ is a vector field.

But in some homework solutions I see without a proof that they also claim that

$ \iint\limits_S F \cdot n\; dA = \iint\limits_S F_1 dydz + F_2 dxdz + F_3 dxy $

How do you prove this claim ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $F \cdot n \, dA = F_1\, dy \wedge dz + F_2\, dx \wedge dz + F_3 \, dx \wedge dy \, = i_{F}\omega_{T}$, where $\omega_{T}$ is the volume form on $T$ (basically, in any oriented coordinate system on $T$, $\omega_T = dx \, dy \, dz = dV$), and $i$ denotes the interior product. A way to see this is to pick oriented coordinates $(x_1, \dots, x_3) \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1 \leq 0\}$ for $T$ for which $S = \partial T$ is given by $\{x_1 = 0\}$, and $e_1$ is the outward unit normal to $S = \partial T$, i.e. $n = e_1$. Then
$$dV = \sqrt{g}\,dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3$$
$$dA = \sqrt{g}\,dx_2 \wedge dx_3,$$
$$F \cdot n \, dA = F_1 \sqrt{g} \, dx_2 \wedge dx_3,$$
$$i_{F}\omega_{T} = i_{F}dV = \sqrt{g}F_1 \, dx_2 \wedge dx_3.$$

If you aren't familiar with this algebraic machinery, do the computations in some coordinate system using things you are familiar with (graph coordinates are an excellent choice!).

Comment: I'm looking for a more traditional  proof. I don't understand the above.

Comment: @Tomer How do you define the objects $F \cdot n\; dA$ and $F_1 dydz + F_2 dxdz + F_3 dxy$ on $S$? They are defined in terms of a parameterization $r(s, t) = (x(s, t), y(s, t), z(s, t))$ of $S = \partial T$. My proof above picked a particular parameterization for which both objects are simple to write down (and I took a small shortcut by using the interior product). Certainly, without loss of generality, we can assume that $r(s, t) = (s, t, \phi(s, t))$, so that $S$ is the graph of the smooth function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. And we can assume that $T$ is the part below the graph.

Comment: (cont.) With this parameterization, all the objects can be calculated explicitly, and they should agree.